# Cookie header is not passed on WS handshake

Tags: node.js, cookies, websocket, header, handshake

I built a NodeJS script which creates a `httpServer` using `http` module, and a `wsServer` using the `ws` module. They are configured to be on same port. The HTTP server responds with a `Set-Cookie` header. By refreshing the page it's visible that the browser sends the cookie in the HTTP request. I opened the console and typed `let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1")`. It sends the request, I receive it on the server side, I can communicate throught it, but the cookie header is not sent in the handshake. I tried it with the local ip too. Below is the server:

```js
; (async () => {
    let ws = require("ws"), http = require("http")

    let httpServer = http.createServer((request, response) => {
        console.log("Received request")
        response.writeHead(200, {"Set-Cookie": "secret=1234567890"})
        response.end()
    })
    httpServer.listen(80, () => console.log("Server is listening"))

    let wsServer = new ws.Server({server: httpServer})
    wsServer.on("connection", conn => {
        conn.on("message", msg => {
            console.log("Received msg: " + msg)
        })
        conn.send("Hello!")
    })
})()
```

Comment: You can't send cookies like that `ws` doesn't accept headers. You can get around that by simply accessing the cookie in the client and passing it in the url of the connection string of the websocket `let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:80/' + cookie)` and then in your server you can see it in `conn.url` in your case

Comment: @C.Gochev, isn't supposed the handshake to happen via HTTP, where the browser appends the cookie header? I have an example of website who does that, and some articles says that it is useful since u can login on the websocket with the HTTP session

Comment: yes, I was wrong you can set cookie like this `const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:80/path', {
  headers: {
    Cookie: 'foo=bar; baz=qux'
  }
});`

Comment: @C.Gochev, I wasn't able to reproduce the example. `WebSocket` class is expecting protocols as second parameter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). I think it should be possible without actually specify the cookies to the `WebSocket` constructor / object

Comment: you do it on the server https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1411

Comment: The websocket must be made on the client, which is a browser. The examples I gave above are for browser-side too

Answer (score 3):

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path', {
  headers: {
    Cookie: 'foo=bar; baz=qux'
  }
});
```